# Kendo rating is displaying as text box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working in asp.net core project. I need to add kendo rating to the view. But it is displaying it as text box. What is wrong here?

My kendo version is 2022.2.510.
My target framework is .net 6.

My cshtml:

[image]

My output:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: did you tried without class="row" ?

Comment: yes it is working when I remove the class row..